# Passing String user input as an argument to a method with class type parameters

Tags: java, hashmap

I am taking an input from user as `String` and I want to pass that String to a method which takes the parameters in the `class` type. 
Is this possible to do so?
I have tried using Hashmap. Will that work?

Following is the relevant code:

`Node` is the class type and `startNode` and `goalNode` are the user `String` inputs

```
public class search {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);         
    filename = input.next();

    File file = new File(filename);

    System.out.print("Enter the start node: ");
    startNode = input.next(); 

    System.out.print("Enter the goal node: ");
    goalNode = input.next(); 

    search s = new search();


    Map<String,Node> map = new HashMap<String,Node>();

    Node start = new Node();
    Node goal = new Node();

    map.put("startNode",start);
    map.put("goalNode",goal); 
    System.out.println(map.get("startNode"));   //IT IS PRINTING NULL HERE            

    s.searchmap(map.get("startNode"), map.get("goalNode")); //CALLING THE METHOD
```

Following is the searchmap method

```
public void searchmap(Node Start, Node Goal) {
...... }
```

For example, lets say if the user enters 's'  for startnode and 'g' for goalnode (strings), I need this to get passed as `Node` type to the method `searchmap`
When I do this, it is returning me null.
Why is that so? Any kind  of clue is much appreciated

Comment: Will presumably `start` is null. Please post a [mcve] rather than just a snippet - if we can reproduce the problem, we'll be in a *much* better position to help you.

Comment: Show your code that assigns values to `start` and `goal` variables.

Comment: I have edited it, please check

Comment: Still code is incomplete

Comment: Oh no!  Do you want me to post the `Node` class aswell? :/ @SauravKumarMehta

Comment: We're just trying to figure out what `start` is and why it's null.

Comment: 'map.put("startNode",start);
    map.put("goalNode",goal); 
    System.out.println(map.get("startNode"));   //IT IS PRINTING NULL HERE'      There is no 'start' and 'goal' defined.

Comment: @SauravKumarMehta I think are they are  been defined in `Map<String,Node> map = new HashMap<String,Node>();` as `Node` ?

Comment: @SauravKumarMehta Sorry I have defined 'start' and 'goal' as `Node start = new Node()` I forgot to add that in the code. Please check it, I have edited it now.

Comment: @rose, something is wrong here.. `Map<String,Node> map = new HashMap<String,Node>();

    Node start = new Node();
    Node goal = new Node();

    map.put("startNode",start);
    map.put("goalNode",goal); 
    System.out.println(map.get("startNode"));`  We have created a node and put in the map. After putting we are reading the same key from same map. It can't be NULL !

Comment: @SauravKumarMehta Then why am I receiving null :/ Still confused

Answer (score 0):

```
if (map.contains("startNode") && map.contains("goalNode")){
 s.searchmap(map.get("startNode"), map.get("goalNode"));
}
```

the method `get()` on `hashmap` will `return` the `value` to which the specified `key` is mapped, or `null` if this `map` contains no mapping for the key. if you are getting a `null` there is no value mapped for the specific key. use `contains` 
on the `map` and check whether there is a value for the specific key this will return true if it does.

Comment: I think `if condition` just validates it but I want to know why start is returning null even though I have mapped it to "startNode" (user input)